# I wonder how to separate all the numerical values from a string without any space just like 123we45rt75

Tags: c++

I read many functions online but they just solve that problem with spaces in strings.so how can I get out all the numerical values from a letter and number 
 sequence.

Comment: `<algorithm>`'s `std::remove_if` + `std::string::erase`.

Comment: Is there anything you tried?

Comment: did you tried doing something ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string oldStr = "123we45rt75";
    string newStr = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < oldStr.length(); i++)
    {
        char val = oldStr[i];
        if( (val <= 90 && val >= 65) || (val <= 122 && val >= 97) )
            newStr += val;
    }
    cout <<"Old String: " << oldStr <<"\nNew String: " << newStr <<     endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [erase/remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "123we45rt75";

    input.erase(
        std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const char c) { return (0 == std::isdigit(c)); }),
        input.end());

    std::cout << input << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) combined with [`std::isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) will let you find all the non-numeric characters. `input.erase()` will then remove the found characters from the string.